# Possibly Unable to Send Email From Within Amazon AWS

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, swiftmailer

I've around at the other questions that seem close to what I'm running into, but I'm not entirely sure if they're the same thing. Basically, I have been writing a website that sends emails to a whole bunch of places, like to a sales person, a factory, and a customer all in one run. On my local test environment this works perfectly, however now that we've pushed the site live to an Amazon AWS server, it only seems to be allowing emails to be sent every once in a while-ish.

I get errors that look like this after only a couple of them are able to get through

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message 'Connection could not be established with host...

My theory is that Amazon is blocking the ports after a couple of sends to thwart people using the servers for spam, but we kind of need this functionality to continue the site running how it should be. Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limits on how much email you can send trough AWS EC2 instance. Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances).

Comment: Yup, thank you. Feel bad that I couldn't find this on my own, but there's a form to fill out here just for requesting that the limits be removed https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true

Comment: @tedder42 why would I use that when we have our own mail server?

Comment: @BrianLeishman it's up to you- but it scales and handles delivery issues much better than you can without adding several FTEs to administer it.

Comment: @tedder42 Still wouldn't be able to receive mail from our customers though

Comment: Your question is about sending email.